# Authenticate without login page using external token in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react webapp, which has neither registration nor login page. User will be authenticated in a different app and on redirecting to my webapp, the token will be passed in the url.

Below are the steps i want to implement :

1. User launches the webapp with url : 127.0.0.1:3000/home/?token=1234
2. Fetch token from the url make post request to server with token and save the token in local storage
3. If response is unauthenticated show error message else render the data returned and show homepage
4. On all consecutive requests send the token to server. If at any point response is unauthenticated, remove the token from local storage.
5. If user is not authenticated, no pages should be shown instead unauthenticated message has to be displayed.

How can i implement this in react. I'm new to react and couldn't find any solution helping my requirements, may be because of my lack of knowledge in react terms. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: All of this is possible in react (and in plain JS). React is primarily for composing UIs. I suggest learning enough JS to implement the various steps you've laid out. With that knowledge you can set up a basic react app and begin piecing it together.

Comment: yes which i will surely do. But i'm on a deadline. I have already built the webapp, only thing pending is adding this authentication, been spending lot of time on this, still couldn't come up with a working solution

Comment: Then you should provide more code or more specific questions. There are numerous possible ways to implement the steps you've laid out, so it will be dependent on what your current app looks like.

Comment: where am i supposed to write the code for this authentication, i mean in which component?  App.js ?

Comment: It can happen in any component - it is very specific to your application setup. Try posting a different question that is more specific and include code.